# General Questions on Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory

The notion I have received while trying to study Measure theory that it is helpful when we move from discrete domain to continuous domain because in discrete domain we can count individual entities but in continuous domain we can't count.

So are we replacing counting to measuring in such scenarios? A set has a measure defined on it such as an open set of $\mathcal{R}$ because its domain is infinite?

Comment: In a rough sense I'd think you are right about this. The problem with the question is that if I "officially" say yes, you may think of all kinds of implications, some of which may hold and some others not... So my impression is that you state a useful and to some extent appropriate intuition about measure theory here, that may not carry you everywhere where measure theory eventually goes. One issue is that if you try to simply carry over counting to continuous spaces, some problems pop up that with simple counting you don't have.

Comment: Also note that on discrete or even finite spaces it's not only about counting, because you can have continuous probabilities, such as for the Bernoulli, binomial, or multinomial distribution.

Comment: @Lewian, alright I did get your point. If you could elaborte the part about "problems pop up that with simple counting you dont have" in the answer then I think it will expand my intuition on measure theory (and counting itself) and I shall consider it valid answer.